# Reboot not starting python app but executing runs with no Errors

Tags: boot-issues, python-3, pi-4

I'm running a bell app connected by ENet between two RPI 4.
The button end works well, but the server end only works when I sign in to activate it. How do I get it to start at start-up in Crontab?

@reboot python3 /home/pi/Coding/BellButton.py >> /home/pi/Coding/BellButton.log

Log has nothing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
import pygame.mixer
import automationhat
import datetime
from datetime import date
import time
import socket

class ButtonServer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, channel, serverIP, serverPort):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.channel = channel
        self.serv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.serv.bind((serverIP,serverPort))
        self.serv.listen(5)
        self.BellButtonOne = -1
        self.BellButtonTwo = -1
        self.BellButtonThree = -1
        self.deamon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.serv.accept()
            from_client = ""

            while True:
                from_client = ""
                data = conn.recv(4096)

                if not data:
                    break

                from_client = data.decode()

                if from_client == "Input 1 On":
                    self.BellButtonOne = 1
                if from_client == "Input 1 Off":
                    self.BellButtonOne = 0

                if from_client == "Input 2 On":
                    self.BellButtonTwo = 1
                if from_client == "Input 2 Off":
                    self.BellButtonTwo = 0

                if from_client == "Input 3 On":
                    self.BellButtonThree = 1
                if from_client == "Input 3 Off":
                    self.BellButtonThree = 0
            conn.close()

B8 = ButtonServer(36,"123.456.789.123",12345)

pygame.mixer.init(48000, -16, 1, 1024)
pygame.mixer.init()

sndAChr = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/ChristmasChurchBell.wav")
sndBChr = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/ChristmasDinnerBell.wav")
sndA = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/ChurchBell.wav")
sndB = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/DinnerBell.wav")
sndB1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/DinnerBell2.wav")
sndB2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/DinnerBell3.wav")
sndC = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/Doing.wav")

snd1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/Doing.wav")
snd15 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/Quarter.wav")
snd30 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/Half.wav")
snd45 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/3Quarter.wav")
snd100 = pygame.mixer.Sound("/home/pi/Public/Active/Hour.wav")

sc1 = pygame.mixer.Channel(1)
sc1.play(snd1)
playDoing = False

DinnerBellNo = 0
while True:
    tnow = datetime.datetime.now()
    today = date.today()
    ChristStartYear = date(today.year,11,19)
    ChristEndYear = date(today.year + 1,1,7)

    if B8.BellButtonOne == 1:
        if pygame.mixer.get_busy():
            playDoing = False
            pygame.mixer.stop()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if B8.BellButtonOne == 0:
            if today >= ChristStartYear and today <= ChristEndYear:
                sc1.play(sndAChr)
            else:
                sc1.play(sndA)
            time.sleep(0.2)

    if B8.BellButtonTwo == 1:
        if pygame.mixer.get_busy():
            playDoing = False
            pygame.mixer.stop()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if B8.BellButtonTwo == 0:
            if today >= ChristStartYear and today <= ChristEndYear:
                sc1.play(sndBChr)
            else:
                if DinnerBellNo == 2:
                    DinnerBellNo += 1
                    sc1.play(sndB2)
                if DinnerBellNo == 1:
                    DinnerBellNo += 1
                    sc1.play(sndB1)
                if DinnerBellNo == 0:
                    DinnerBellNo += 1
                    sc1.play(sndB)
                if DinnerBellNo == 3:
                    DinnerBellNo = 0
                time.sleep(0.2)

    if B8.BellButtonThree == 1:
        if pygame.mixer.get_busy():
            playDoing = False
            pygame.mixer.stop()
        time.sleep(0.2)
        if B8.BellButtonThree == 0:
            sc1.play(sndAChr)
            time.sleep(0.2)



    #On Board Buttons
    #if automationhat.input.one.is_on():
    #    if pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    #        playDoing = False
    #        pygame.mixer.stop()
    #    time.sleep(0.2)
    #    if automationhat.input.one.is_off():
    #        if today >= ChristStartYear and today <= ChristEndYear:
    #            sc1.play(sndAChr)
    #        else:
    #            sc1.play(sndA)
    #        time.sleep(0.2)

    #if automationhat.input.two.is_on():
    #    if pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    #        playDoing = False
    #        pygame.mixer.stop()
    #    time.sleep(0.2)
    #    if automationhat.input.two.is_off():
    #        if today >= ChristStartYear and today <= ChristEndYear:
    #            sc1.play(sndBChr)
    #        else:
    #            if DinnerBellNo == 2:
    #                DinnerBellNo += 1
    #                sc1.play(sndB2)
    #            if DinnerBellNo == 1:
    #                DinnerBellNo += 1
    #                sc1.play(sndB1)
    #            if DinnerBellNo == 0:
    #                DinnerBellNo += 1
    #                sc1.play(sndB)
    #            if DinnerBellNo == 3:
    #                DinnerBellNo = 0
    #        time.sleep(0.2)

    #if automationhat.input.three.is_on():
    #    if pygame.mixer.get_busy():
    #        playDoing = False
    #        pygame.mixer.stop()
    #    time.sleep(0.2)
    #    if automationhat.input.three.is_off():
    #        sc1.play(sndAChr)
    #        time.sleep(0.2)

    #Chime Clock
    if tnow.hour >= 6 and tnow.hour <= 22:
        if tnow.hour % 1 == 0 and tnow.minute == 0 and tnow.second == 0:
            if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
                sc1.play(snd100)
                playDoing = True
            time.sleep(0.2)

    if tnow.hour >= 6 and tnow.hour <= 21:
        if tnow.minute % 15 == 0:
            if tnow.minute == 15 and tnow.second == 0:
                if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
                    sc1.play(snd15)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
            if tnow.minute == 30 and tnow.second == 0:
                if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
                    sc1.play(snd30)
                    time.sleep(0.2)
            if tnow.minute == 45 and tnow.second == 0:
                if not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
                    sc1.play(snd45)
                    time.sleep(0.2)

    if playDoing == True and not pygame.mixer.get_busy():
        h=tnow.hour
        if h > 12:
            h -= 12
        sc1.play(snd1, h-1)
        playDoing = False
```

Comment: please format all of your code, not just parts of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ingo has provided a good and correct answer. This answer is provided to augment [Ingo's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105315/83790) & provide details that may be helpful to your understanding.

Know that `cron` is useful, but to use it effectively, you should understand its limitations.

#### 1. `cron` has no knowledge of the state of your system during the boot process.

This means that it is your responsibility to ensure that the services required to execute your `@reboot` entry in your `crontab` file are available ***before*** your script/program is started. In general, this can often be accomplished by simply adding a `sleep` statement to your `@reboot` entry in `crontab`.

#### 2. `cron` runs under a different `environment` than your `user id`.

When you are logged in under a `user id` (`pi` for example), the OS has created an [`environment`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-environment.htm) that includes (among other things) a default `path` in which to find executables. However, when your `cron` job executes, it is ***NOT*** executed with all of the same environment variables as your `user id`. Since `cron`'s `PATH` environment variable is not defined same as your `user id`, then you should use a "complete" file specification (path) for your executable to ensure your system knows which file(s) you intend to execute or use.

If you want to explore this business of the `environment` in more detail:

- To get your (`user id`) environment at the `bash` command line: `printenv`
- To get the `cron` environment, use [this technique](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/WhatIsCronEnvironment.md)

#### 3. a failed `cron` job needs your help to tell you if or why it fails to execute.

This is related to the limitation above; i.e. your `cron` job is not actually run under your `user id`. Linux utilizes [three (3) "streams" to communicate](https://www.howtogeek.com/435903/what-are-stdin-stdout-and-stderr-on-linux/) with a user: `stdin`, `stderr` and `stdout`. When you use a terminal to interact with your RPi, the system knows where to direct your input/commands at the terminal (`stdin` to a process), and it also knows to direct any output (`stderr` and `stdout`) from that process to your terminal. ***HOWEVER***, unless you tell the system, it doesn't know where to direct the `cron` user's output or error messages. Thus, when a `cron` job fails to run, an error message is (may be) generated, but the system doesn't know where this "stream" should be directed, and you (your `user id`) doesn't have the benefit of this feedback. It's a bit like driving with your eyes closed. Recovering the `stderr` output from `cron` is accomplished with a simple "redirect" to a file.

#### OVERCOMING `cron`'s LIMITATIONS

Fortunately, it's fairly straightforward to deal with all three of these limitations. I'll use your `cron` job to illustrate how you might deal with all these limitations by modifying your one line `cron` job:

```bsh
@reboot ( /bin/sleep 30; /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Coding/BellButton.py  > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1)
```

If any of this is unclear, please let us know.

Comment: Awesome!! I have fooled around for two weeks just to try and get this going! A simple wait/sleep that fixed the problem.

Comment: Another problem; How would I make it so if the connection is broken so it reconnects?

Comment: When the server side looses power at power outages but the client doesn't how do I check if that happens to shut down the connection on both ends and reconnect?

Comment: or when the client looses power/shuts down how do I reconnect them?

Answer (score 2):

You tagged the question with **python-3** but you call everywhere **python** that is calling python 2. Because you don't tell us how do you start the script after login it is unclear why it then unexpected runs. You should also use full path calls in `crontab`:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Coding/BellButton.py >> /home/pi/Coding/BellButton.log
```

Also correct the *shebang* (first line) in your script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: Sorry Guys!, I don't know why it didn't format the code right, I pasted it and look good to me, after posting it was all jumbled together.

Comment: I know I need to make sure that all resources are running before executing, not sure how though.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @ingo has stated, crontab can often start running your script before the Pi is able to do any networking, so it might be worth adding a `sleep` function to your code after your imports.