# execute a line of code in the terminal after Pi is booting

Tags: pi-4, boot, puredata

I need to write this line of code on my Pi terminal in order to make my music software to work

```
sudo systemctl restart my_puredata.service
```

How can I make Pi automatically execute this line of code every time is booting?

Is it also to give it some delay time? Meaning run this line of code but only after 6 seconds from boot?

Thanks

Comment: Search for run a command after boot.  This question has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: I have added this line: sudo systemctl restart my_puredata.service 
to the rc-local file. but it not seems to help. is there anyway I could delay that command in a few seconds?

Comment: Use `sudo systemctl enable my_puredata.service` to get it running at every boot.

Answer (score 0):

https://linuxhint.com/use-etc-rc-local-boot/ You don't need the "sudo" but it is important to remember /etc/rc.local is discontinued and replaced by Systemd, and instructions for using that are further down the same page

Answer (score 0):

Here, because of the delay requested, I would choose to use `cron`.

Create a script `/usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 6
systemctl restart my_puredata.service
```

and make it executable (`chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh`)

In the crontab for root add (`sudo crontab -e`)

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh
```

Comment: how do I creat a script: " /usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh"

Comment: I type into terminal : sudo nano /usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh I then write the script you suggested. after saving I run: chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh . I'm getting error: chmod changing permission of ... : Operation not permitted . How can I fix that?

Comment: `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/puredata.cron.sh`

Comment: how can I delete the puredata,cron.sh thatI created? I went into: ls  /usr/local/bin/ . I then type: rm puredata.cron.sh. but it not give me to delete it

Comment: The questions that you ask in the comments show that you need an introduction to the Linux command line. Google "introduction to the linux command line" ans select one.

Answer (score 0):

In most modern Linux systems (incl the RPi OS), what happens during the boot process is controlled by the [`init` process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init). While there are [several different `init` software implementations](https://www.slant.co/topics/4663/%7Elinux-init-systems), many of today's distros (including RPi OS) have adopted `systemd` - as you have recognized by use of your prototype `sudo systemctl restart my_puredata.service`.

In general, for RPi OS, you have two good options for starting a program during or shortly after the boot process:

1. Write a systemd unit
2. Set up a `cron` job under the `@reboot` schedule

If your program/service has complex dependencies, and/or needs to start at a specific point in the boot process, you may be best-served by creating a `systemd` unit. If your program is not that complex, `cron` may serve your needs with less effort. *(FYI: The `cron` daemon is actually started by `systemd`)*

You didn't provide much information on your application/service, and therefore it's not clear from here what your best choice is. However, both `cron` and `systemd` provide facilities for delaying the start of a service by a specified `sleep` time:

- For `systemd` it's rather more arcane, but there's a detailed description in [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001223/how-to-ensure-that-there-is-a-delay-before-a-service-is-started-in-systemd)
- For `cron` it's simpler - just append a `sleep` command prior to the command/script to start your service: e.g. in your `crontab`:

```bash
@reboot /usr/bin/sleep 6; /path/to/startscript > /home/pi/cronjoblog 2>&1
```

Here's a link to another answer that provides [a comparison between `cron` and `systemd`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105326/83790).

One final note: If you're using `cron`, and the service requires root privileges, you must use the `root crontab`; i.e. `sudo crontab -e` instead of `crontab -e`.